# Jquery datepicker and a multiple on select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, jsfiddle

I have a form with a jquery date select and radio buttons like below

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="5506_datepick_1"></input>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="5506_protocol_protocol_1" type="radio" value="protocol 1" name="5506[protocol]">pp1</input>
        <input id="5506_protocol_protocol_2" type="radio" value="protocol 2" name="5506[protocol]">pp2</input>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="5507_datepick_2"></input>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="5507_protocol_protocol_1" type="radio" value="protocol 1" name="5507[protocol]">pp1</input>
        <input id="5507_protocol_protocol_2" type="radio" value="protocol 2" name="5507[protocol]">pp2</input>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Whenever someone selects both the inputs on each row(example: radio for 5506* and date picker for 5506*) I want to be able to trigger a function regardless of the select order.
I have tried the following (in Js Fiddle) but its useless.
Anyone have any ideas on how I can go about this unobtrusively.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/striderinc/mA5dN/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input selector is using `^=`, which matches the exact START of a value, yet your values don't start with that value. I suggest changing that to `*=` so it searches anywhere within the ID. [Reference jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Second, you're forgetting a closing `'` quote for that selector.

That fixes the selector issues for activation. Now you just need to trigger a common function to check if both Date and Radio (in the same line) have been filled out.

[Fixed JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mA5dN/2/)

This activates the `checkProtocol()` function when a date is selected and passes the input text element along to it.

```
$(this).datepicker({
    onSelect: function() { checkProtocol( this ) }
});
```

This activates the `checkProtocol()` function when a radio button has been selected for that group and passes that element along as a parameter.

```
$("input[id*='protocol_protocol']").change( function() { checkProtocol(this) } );
```

Comment: that does not answer my question. sorry about the mistake I am getting all the selectors right however I Want to trigger an event on select of both the events in a single row.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that shortly after posting, I'm updating the Fiddle with more infos.

Comment: it's working for me... when you select a date, it fires the alert... what are you still missing?

Comment: His question is basically a form "validation" type deal, which I didn't answer yet.

Comment: @webeno I am trying to change the code so that whenever both the inputs on each row of the table are selected I want to submit an ajax request or in the fiddle case an alert!! I cannot use jquery multiple selectors since the text field is a datepicker and It will not trigger

Comment: @Stacked-for-life Updated my answer, which should help with your requirements.

Comment: Awesome ! Wish I could give a + 2